# style.display = 'none' works in IE8 but not IE11

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-11

my system works on IE8,now this customer want to use this system on windows7 + IE11. this code "style.display = 'none' " does not work.

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
     function hide(){ 
        var type2=document.getElementsByName("type2"); 
        for(var i=0;i<type2.length;i++){
              type2[i].style.display="none"; 
         }
     } 
</script>
```

```html
<table border="0" > 
     <tr> 
        <td nowrap align="left" id="type2">
             <bean:message bundle="ests" key="part"/>
        </td> 
       <td nowrap align="left" id="type2"><bean:message bundle="ests" key="ests.estRequest.label.businessKanriNo"/>
      </td> 
  <td nowrap align="left" id="type2"><html:text maxlength="7" property="businessKanriNo" size="15" />&nbsp;
     </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Hi! Please add some code?

Comment: Try `display :none !important.`

Comment: <script language="JavaScript">
  function loadpage(){
   var type2=document.getElementsByName("type2");
   for(var i=0;i<type2.length;i++){
    type2[i].style.display="none";
   }
  }
  </script><table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
       <td nowrap align="left" id="type2"><bean:message bundle="ests" key="ests.estRequest.label.function.part"/></td> 
       </tr>
     </table>

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code there. Code in comments is too difficult to read!

Comment: Has edited the question, and added my code

Comment: You're using `getElementsByName` to select an element with ID. That's the issue. Also, based on your code it seems that you have multiple instances of the same ID. IDs must be unique in your document. Go with HTML classes instead.

Comment: I hava multiple instances of the same ID

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.btn').css('display','block','important');
```

Or yyou can use this in css
     `display:none !important`

Or you can you hide() in jquery to hide an element. Like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('p').hide(); //if you wanna hide <p>
 }):
```

Comment: In CSS is't OK,in javaScript is't not wroks

Comment: It is not javascript. Its jquery.

Comment: Where btn is the class of the element you wanna hide.

Comment: our system is too old, it's not import jquery,I can't use  jquery's method.

Comment: Wait a minute. jQuery *IS* JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName is causing this problem use getElementsById. It will solve your problem. Correct code is given below.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
     function hide(){ 
        var type2=document.getElementById("type2"); 
        for(var i=0;i<type2.length;i++){
              type2[i].style.display="none"; 
         }
     } 
</script>
```

You can also use `jQuery` property to select this element.:

```
$("#type2").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: Did you problem is solved? by using this code. I have updated my answer as now I have the problem code.

Comment: write to "$("td#type2").css("display", "none");" it's ok, but i'm "$("#type2").css("display", "none");" can't to be hide. Very strange